$\emptyset \in \emptyset$ Is this right?
I just took a test, and at a question next two statements were right answers.

$\left(\{x\} \in \{x,\{x\}\}\right) \land (\{x\}\subseteq\{x,\{x\}\})$

$(\emptyset \in \{\emptyset\}) \land (\emptyset\subseteq\{\emptyset\})$


If these are right statements, then '$\emptyset \in \emptyset$' is a correct statement. But I learned $\emptyset$ has no elements, so how can this be correct? Is this a wrong question?

$\emptyset \in {\emptyset}$ is not the same thing that $\emptyset \in \emptyset$. Moreover $\emptyset \subseteq {\emptyset}$ is true because... $\emptyset$ is empty. So you can say what you want about its non-existent elements.

Both initial statements are correct:

$\{x, \{x\}\}$ is a set containing 2 elements $x$ and $\{x\}$, hence $\{x\} \in \{x, \{x\}\}$. Furthermore, as $x \in \{x, \{x\}\}$, $\{x\} \subset \{x, \{x\}\}$
$\{\emptyset\}$ is the set containing the empty set as sole element, hence $\emptyset \in \{\emptyset\}$. Furthermore the empty set ($\emptyset$) is by definition a subset of any set, hence $\emptyset \subset \{\emptyset\}$.

But :

If these are right statements, then '∅ ∈ ∅' is correct statement.

is plain wrong, because $\emptyset$ is not $\{\emptyset\}$: the former is the empty set (no elements at all) while the latter is the set containing $one$ element which is the empty set.
